# ¿Procesar números personalizados con separadores de miles por el usuario, de HTML a Django con python?

Tags: python, html5, django, django-models

Tengo un formulario HTML con 2 campos que solo reciben valores flotantes o enteros , necesito habilitarle al usuario que pueda insertar separadores de miles en el número y que Python los reciba y los formatee para enviarlo a la base de datos Mysql con tipo de dato **FloatField()**.

***Ejemplo del Formulario.***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>FORMULARIO</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center">

        <form method="post" action="/insertar">
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <label>COSTO 1</label>
            <input type="text" name="costo1"><br>
            <label>COSTO 2</label>
            <input type="text" name="costo2">

            <br><br><br>

            <input type="submit" name="" value="ENVIAR COSTO">

        </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

***Ejemplo del modelo en Django.***

```py
class Costos(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    costol = models.FloatField()
    costo2 = models.FloatField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = "costos"
```

**Vista que guarda los datos**

```py
from .models import Costos


def insertar(request):
    costo1 = request.POST.get("costo1")
    costo2 = request.POST.get("costo2")
    Costos(costo1=costo1, costo2=costo2).save()
```

**NOTA** : No puedo cambiar de FloatField a otro tipo de dato porque la base de datos ya está poblada con costos sin formatear. Lo ideal sería hacerlo con este tipo de dato en la base de datos MySql.

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega el mínimo código necesario para reproducir el problema como texto, no como imagen.

Comment: Listo amigo , gracias por la sugerencia, ya he actualizado la pregunta